# Zend framework registration + email confirmation

Tags: email, zend-framework, confirmation-email

Do you know how to do registration in Zend that require email confirmation? Is Zend has any mechanism to do it easy? I have found only classes to send emails but I dont know that Zend has special support for email confirmation in registration process?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're describing is a business process and as such, is not covered by the framework. You would have to build it yourself.

The basic process would go

1. Generate a unique token and store it against your user record
2. Create an email containing a link to the confirmation page. Include the unique token in your link as well as any other identifying fields you require
3. On the confirmation page, check the token against the one saved with the user record. If they match, complete the registration.